# spring api - jackson serialize an object to an array

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I'm encountering a problem about the way jackson serialize an object.

I have a class

```
public class Solution {     
   private int id;  
   private String description;
      private User user;    
     private Date createdDate;  
     private Date lastModifiedDate;     
     private int isActive; 
}
```

I only wanted to select id and description from database:

```
public List<Solution> getSolutionForSearching() {
   String hql = "SELECT id,description  FROM Solution";         
     Session session = solutionDao.getSession();        
     Query query =session.createQuery(hql);         
     return query.list();   
}
```

And I expected the response is an array of objects

```
 [ { id: 35, description: "12" }, { id: 36, description: "1a"   }]
```

but the obtained result is an array of arrays

```
[ [35, "12" ], [  36, "1a"  ]]
```

How to serialize the response data to match the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hql query does not return instances of type `Solution`. Instead it returns int, String pairs. So the Jackson cannot map them to the correct form.

You should either return complete objects `Solution` from the database, or you map the results of the query to `Solution` object before you pass it to Jackson.

Currently your `Solution` object is very small, so you don't have to worry about the performance. Just modify the hql query like this:

```
String hql = "SELECT solution FROM Solution solution";
```

Comment: He could also use a custom constructor and have Hibernate create the object form him, like `SELECT new Solution(s.id, s.description) FROM Solution s`

Comment: Thank you guys very much. it's really helpful for me.